# POST does not send information

Tags: php

menu.php

```
      $producten = '';
      //Get the headings from the database
      try{
        
        $data = $verbinding->query("SELECT product_category, product_id, parent FROM Productcategory ORDER BY product_category");

        # haal alle gegevens in 1 keer uit de database
        $categories = $data->fetchAll();
        
        foreach($categories as $cat) {
          if ($cat["parent"] === "-1"){
            echo '<form action="product-list.php" method="post">
            <input type="submit" name="cats" value="'. $cat['product_category'] .'"></form>';

            if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){
              if(isset($_POST['cats'])){
                echo "test";
                echo $_POST['cats'];
              if($_POST['cats'] == $cat['product_category']){
              $producten = $cat['product_id'];
              echo $_POST['cats'];
              
           }
           }
         }
            
        }
      }
   
    }
      
      catch (PDOException $e){
        echo "Kan rubrieken niet laden";
      }
```

product-list.php

```
                                $stmt = $verbinding->query("SELECT product_category, product_id, parent FROM Productcategory ORDER BY product_category");

                                $categorien = $stmt->fetchAll();
                               
                                    foreach($categorien as $cats){
                                      if($cats['parent'] === $producten){
                                       
                                        echo '<form action="product-list.php" method="POST">
                                        <input type="submit" name="cat2" value="'. $cats['product_category'] .'"></form>';
                                        echo $producten;                                      
                                        echo $product;
                                        

                                       /* COMMENT FOR THE NEXT TIME I WORK ON THIS. IF I PUT THE IF STATEMENT BENEATH IN THE NEXT FOREACH LOOP IT ONLY GETS THE LAST VALUE OF
                                       THE CURRENT FOREACH LOOP IT IS IN. BUT IF I PUT IT IN THIS FOREACH LOOP IT DOES NOT GET A VALUE AT ALL...*/
                                        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){
                                            echo $_POST['cat2'];
                                            if(isset($_POST['cat2'])){
                                                if($_POST['cat2'] === $cats['product_category']){
                                                $product = $cats['product_id'];
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                      
                                    }
                                }
                                
                                        foreach($categorien as $cate){
                                            
                                                if($cate['parent'] === $cats['product_id']){
                                                echo '<form action="product-list.php" method="post">
                                                <input type="submit" name="categorien" value="'. $cate['product_category'] .'"></form>';
                                                echo $product;
                                                }
                                            }
```

Hello people I have a question. As you can see I have 2 pieces of code on different tabs. What I want to do is have a dropdown menu with values from the database, and if I click one of the values it shows the sub-values of that value on the right side of the page. So its not a multi layered dropdown-menu. I have succeeded to do that for 1 level deeper, but cant seem to be able to continue. my code just does not get past the if(isset($_POST['cat2'] bit. It seems to not register at all that I have clicked on the form with the name cat2. Could someone help please? Thank you for your time.

Comment: *"if I click one of the values it shows the sub-values of that value on the right side of the page"* - the page is displayed on a different window (or a tabs, or in an iframe)?

Comment: @BagusTesa So the values are available in my index.php as a menu. And if I click one of them I go to product-list.php so yeah I do go to another page.